# HIghcharts and dynamic json

Tags: javascript, php, json, highcharts

Im using a php to pass json to Highcharts. My php is returning json that looks like this:

```
{"A":5,"B":12,"C":5,"D":11,"E":6}
```

How would I go about building a chart with the categories: A,B,C,D,E and the Values: 5,12,5,11,6?

I've tried using:

```
$.getJSON("test.php", function(json){
            $.each(json, function(i, e) {
             options.series.data= json;
                });
            chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);

            });
```

I know this is just taking all of the json and trying to dump it in the series.data which is wrong. What is the best way to split up the keys and values? Should this be handled on the php side or in javascript?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I've create a class for you, so you can use it anywhere:

```
HighChartObject = function (obj) {
    if (typeof obj === 'string') obj = JSON.parse(obj);

    for (var key in obj) {
        this[key] = obj[key];
    }
}

HighChartObject.prototype.getDataArray = function () {
    var arr = [];

    for (var key in this) {
        if (this.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            arr.push(obj[key]);
        }
    }

    return arr;
}

HighChartObject.prototype.getCategoriesArray = function () {
    var arr = [];

    for (var key in this) {
        if (this.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            arr.push(key);
        }
    }

    return arr;
}
```

Usage:

```
var json = '{ "A": 5, "B": 12, "C": 5, "D": 11, "E": 6 }';
var obj = new HighChartObject(json);

$("#container").highcharts({
    xAxis: {
        categories: obj.getCategoriesArray()
    },
    series: [
        {
            name: "MyName",
            data: obj.getDataArray()
        }
    ]
});
```

And **[here there is a FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/FRjpW/)**, so you can play with it!

I don't know if this is exactly what you need, but I think you can improve the code for your needs, right?

I hope it can help you =)

Comment: Really nice piece of code. I guess it could work faster if you simply loop over all properties just once, when initializing object :)